# asp.net user Authorization and Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, authorization

I want to write a web application and I am trying to figure out what are my possibilites regarding user Authorization and Authentication, for what i read so far:

1. using asp.net membership and role management
2. using oauth or openId controls
3. implementing myself this portion (this looks like a lot of hard work and i am not sure if its worth it)

What do you recommend or if you can link to more information regarding this issue

thank you

Doron

Comment: The three are possible and your question is not constructive. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ASP.NET [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx), [`ProfileProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileprovider.aspx) and [`RoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) is the best solution IMO as it makes your application plug-able, works *with* the framework, and it forces a nice layer of abstraction.

I don't recommend using the static classes to access the providers, I would always take a dependency on the provider directly through DI and keep things testable.

```
var service = new UserService(Membership.Provider);
service.MyUserAction("myusername");

// rather than

var user = Membership.GetUser("myusername");
...
```

`OAuth` or `OpenId` can be used to complement and extend a basic forms implementation, allowing users to login through other providers, but then map to a local user so that you can store additional meta data.

You don't really *have* to use the providers to take advantage of `ASP.NET` authentication, making use of the auth cookie through [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) is a nice shortcut for post authentication.

Rolling your own is a bad idea. The built it mechanisms are not fool proof, but it's a solid base implementation that avoids the basic gotchas that most people fall for. Never use `Session` for any `authentication` or `authorisation` logic as it's highly insecure.